# objective C-How to get a point marked on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to draw a circle on a UIView. The position of the view will be some values dynamically send ie,
for example if the height of the view is 100 and the value is 60  the point should be plotted at the 60th position inside the view

this is the code used to display two views

```
UIView *img=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,67,300)];
img.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:img];
UIView *circle=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,50,50)];
circle.alpha=0.5;
circle.layer.cornerRadius=50;
circle.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[img addSubview:circle];
```

How can i achieve this ? Anybody please help..

---edit---
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make `UIView` circular like this :

```
circle.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.size.width/2;
circle.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

To move the circle to new place, you can do following :

```
circle.center = CGPointMake (newCenterX,newCenterY);
```

Comment: I dint mean to change the corner radius but move the circle to a place over the view with dynamic values

Comment: You can set the "center" of your Circle, even you can set the "frame" of your circle. Set whatever is convenient for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
- (void)drawCricleAtPoint:(CGPoint)center inView:(UIView *)superview withRadius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    CGPoint originOfSquare = CGPointMake((center.x-radius), (center.y-radius));
    CGRect squareFrame = CGRectZero;
    squareFrame.origin = originOfSquare;
    squareFrame.size = CGSizeMake(2*radius, 2*radius);
    UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:squareFrame];
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = radius; //half of the width if enclosing square
    [circle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [superview addSubview:circle];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
-(void)drawCircle{
UIView *img=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,67,300)];
img.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:img];
UIView *circle=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,50,50)];
circle.alpha=0.5;
circle.layer.cornerRadius=circle.frame.size.width/2;
circle.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[img addSubview:circle];
}



note: change only the line

circle.layer.cornerRadius=circle.frame.size.width/2;
```

Comment: I dint mean to change the corner radius but move the circle to a place over the view with dynamic values

Comment: float y = 200;
UIView *circle=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,y,50,50)];

Comment: you can do it with above alongside y axis

Comment: but what if the value is above the view say 320 ?

Comment: UIView *img=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,67,300)];
here height = 300; So you should set y <300.

Comment: but if you set y =320; you will see nothing of the circle. because your circle will set outside of the boundary  img(0,70,67,300)

Comment: ok..thanks for the  help. :)

Comment: CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) formate

Answer (score 0):

you just simple store the value of x and y which is dynamically come. so try it. it may be help you.

```
UIView *img=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,67,300)];
img.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:img];
UIView *circle=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,50,50)];
circle.alpha=0.5;
circle.layer.cornerRadius=50;
circle.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[img addSubview:circle];
```